# What type of redirect is this?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, redirect, php-7, redirect-url

While I'm studying a line of code in magento vendor file I found this code:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```

What does this `'*/*/'` means and where does this redirects.
Hope I will get more clarification.

Comment: On which controller file you get this?

Answer (score 9):

If you need to know detail about the following code then read the following:

```
$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```

First * means current route and second * means current controller. Let me explain it in detail with example.

Suppose you are submitting any form to **http://example.com/someroute/somecontroller/someaction**. Then in this case if you are using `$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');` then it will redirect you to current route and current  controller like **http://example.com/someroute/somecontroller/index**. Index action is here because if you have not mentioned any action `$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');`.

Suppose you are submitting any form to **http://example.com/someroute/somecontroller/someaction**. Then in this case if you are using $`resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/test');` then it will redirect you to current route and current  controller like **http://example.com/someroute/somecontroller/test**. Test action is here because if you have not mentioned any action `$resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/test');`.

Summary: First * for route, second * for controller and third for action.

Answer (score 5):

It is used to redirect current route, current controller's index action.

Let say if you are currently browsing

> checkout/index/customaction

if you are using this code in custom action controller, then it will redirect you to checkout/index/index
So in this case

> `checkout/index/index = '*/*/' OR '*/*/Index' (both are same);`

here

> First `*` denotes current route, in our example its checkout
>
> Second `*` denotes controller, in our example its Index
>
> Third `*` denotes action (if available otherwise Index by default)

if you use

> `'*/*/test'`

Then in our example it will redirect you to checkout/index/test.

> `'*/*/*'` means current action

Also we can say that `'*/*'` will redirect you to the current module's index controller

I hope you got idea on it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```

This will redirect you to the current module's index controller. For example you are on customer/account/create controller then If I write this line of code in controller it'll take you to customer/account/index controller.